# Excel VBA check if cell words contained in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if all words of one cell contained in sub words of another cell.

For example:

[image]

A1 contained in B1, but A2 not contained in B1.

Comment: You should raise a job offer if you search for someone who is doing the entire work for you. Otherwise show us what you already have and where your struggle. In general: split the content of both cells in arrays and compare them afterwards element by element with InStr function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *UDF()* will determine if all the words in cell **Little** appear in cell **Big**:

```
Public Function AreIn(Little As String, Big As String) As Boolean
   Dim good As Boolean, aLittle, aBig, L, B

   AreIn = False
   aLittle = Split(LCase(Little), " ")
   aBig = Split(LCase(Big), " ")

   For Each L In aLittle
      good = False
      For Each B In aBig
         If L = B Then
            good = True
         End If
      Next B
      If good = False Then Exit Function
   Next L
   AreIn = True
End Function
```

Here a *"word"* is a set of characters that do not include a space.  The test is case-insensitive.  Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I edited your code in my question and now that's what I meant.