# Excel VBA check if cell words contained in another cell (Case Sensitive)

Tags: excel, vba, case-sensitive

I want to check if multiple words in a cell is present in another cell (it should be case sensitive). I am using "|" to differentiate between different strings. I have provided an example of what I want the code to return vs the output I'm getting. I replaced *If L = B Then* with **If StrComp(L, B, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then** but that didn't work.

P.S. - I am using this code from a previously answered code:
[Excel VBA check if cell words contained in another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251713/excel-vba-check-if-cell-words-contained-in-another-cell)

Code is given below:

```
   Public Function AreIn(Little As String, Big As String) As Boolean
   Dim good As Boolean, aLittle, aBig, L, B

   AreIn = False
   aLittle = Split(LCase(Little), "|")
   aBig = Split(LCase(Big), "|")

   For Each L In aLittle
      good = False
      For Each B In aBig
         If L = B Then
            good = True
         End If
      Next B
      If good = False Then Exit Function
   Next L
   AreIn = True
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You certainly don't need to write a custom function for this. Native Excel functions can do this just fine. What version of Excel are you using? `=ISNUMBER(FIND("|"&B2&"|","|"&A2&"|"))` is all you need.

Comment: Version 2102.  I am using this function in another macro formula:

=IF(Results!$I$5="Regex",RegxFunc(Check!C2,Results!$E$5),VBAProject.Module1.AreIn(Check!C2,Results!$E$5))

Macro Code:
Range("B2").Select

ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=IF(Results!R4C9=""Regex"",RegxFunc(Check!RC,Results!R4C5),VBAProject.Module1.AreIn(Check!RC,Results!R4C5))"
 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Worksheets("Check").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Comment: I can't read code from a comment, update your question rather and let us know how the two are linked and what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you! Your formula works. I was just curious to know whether the formula would  still work even if the no. of strings would change on the either sides (for some records the  input can have more than 10 words and for few just one)